# Showing image processing for 10 sec

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How can I show an loading or progress bar on screen for 10 seconds?

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">

</script>
<script>
$(function(){

    $('#loadaing').hide();

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#loading').fadeIn('slow');
    },1000);

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form  action="" >
<br />
<input type="submit"  value="Click!" style="width:100px;" onclick="$('#loading').show();"/>
</form>
<div id="loading" style="display:none;"><img src="loading_orange.gif" alt="" />Loading!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to achieve the given loading image, showing it for at least 10 sec when I click on the submit button.

Comment: So add another timeout?

Comment: What makes you think your users want to wait for 10 seconds ?

Comment: @adeneo  yes i want user wait 10 sec

Comment: Nobody is going to wait for 10 secs nowdays. Btw. `loadaing !== loading`.

Comment: My point was that nobody else wants to wait that long. Why add uneccessary periods of waiting, it's just annoying.

Comment: @adeneo  here this is my requirement

Answer (score 0):

As it stands your #loading element will take 1 second before it fades in, since we've delayed that function call for the fadeIn. If we want to have it hidden, display when a button is clicked, then fade out a certain time later, we need to fade it in, then set the fadeOut call within setTimeout

```js
//cache the DOM element so we dont query it over and over
var imageLoading = $('.image-loading')

//hide it 
imageLoading.hide();

//add event listner to the trigger button

$('.trigger-loading').on('click', function () {
    
    //show it
    imageLoading.fadeIn();
    
    //wait a second and then hide it again
    setTimeout(function () {
        imageLoading.fadeOut();
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}
.image-loading {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.image-loading h3 {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
.trigger-loading {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-loading">
    <h3>Image Loading</h3>
</div>
<button class="trigger-loading">Show image loading</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bhwg87ks/

Answer (score 0):

```js
<input type="submit"  value="Click!" style="width:100px;" onclick="$('#loading').show(0, function () { setTimeout(function(){ $('#loading').hide(); }, 10000); });;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are fading in loader on doc ready , just do it like this :

```
<script>
$(function(){

    $('#loadaing').hide(); //Hide loader firstly

});

function showLoader(){

  $('#loading').fadeIn('slow'); //First display loader
  setTimeout(function(){
     $('#loading').fadeOut('slow'); //Then hide it after specified time
  },1000);

}
</script>
```

And call it onclick :

```
<input type="submit"  value="Click!" style="width:100px;" onclick="showLoader();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain events and use delay

```
$('#loading')
    .fadeIn('slow')
    .delay(10000)
    .fadeOut("fast");
```

Answer (score 0):

I just use this simple one. Only issue is it shows if not processing.

```
 <input type="submit" value="Upload Document" class=verd9 onclick="javascript:showElement('process')">

 <div class="general" id="process" style="display:none;" align=center>
 <br>
 Compressing and Uploading
 <br><br>
 <img src="images/processing3.gif">
 <br><br>
 Please Wait
 <br>
 </div>
```